# how to avoid to put cursor on every line at Vs Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide

When trying to select a code snippet or all of the code at visual studio code, it thinks that I want to put a cursor to every line.

It supposed to select the whole line, and I don't have to move my mouse at the end of the line in order to select everything. You can see the result from the image. how can I get back to normal?

[image: see image here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't notice I opted for column selection mode under selection tab. so problem solved.